# How to implement CSS Grid in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, grid-layout

I have a simple Grid with two responsible images, but I need it to work in Internet Explorer 11 too. I tried to use `Autoprefixer`, but it didn't worked.

My live code: https://codepen.io/XTeoos/pen/QWELojR

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:

    ". .";
}
.g1 {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container"> 
    <img class=g1 src="1.jpg">
    <img class=g1 src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IE doesn't support grids well, you have to define grid columns to display the image properly.
Try this

```css
.parent{
display: grid;
display: -ms-grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.image1{
grid-column: 1;
-ms-grid-column: 1;
-ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.image2{
grid-column: 2;
-ms-grid-column: 2;
-ms-grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img class="image1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="ex" />
<img class="image2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="ex2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the very didactic answer!
One last doubt if I may
I'm using the code that you sent but when I use the image as a link (href) it breaks. Do you have any idea of a solution?

Comment: You cannot add href on a <img> tag. Use anchor and add image inside it. 
Ex: 
<a href=""><img></a>
If you got your answer, please accept the answer, so this issue is closed.

Comment: @MatheusOliveiraa I'm in favor of this answer and the comment above. You can't use `href` in `<img>`. To make it compatible with IE and other modern browsers, you can detect IE in css using media queries and use the css as IE specific. You can also check this more complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/1j0uc6ys/. I suggest you can mark this answer so that it can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks! Its worked using  onclick="window.location='LINK'